# JQuery DataTable Not Displaying JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, rest, datatables

I have REST service in server which returns JSON data. I am getting the value and can able to print on the JQuery client using the below snippet. But the datatabe i am using is not rendering  the information. I also used aoColumns in the datatable to map the JSON data to the table column. What could be gone wrong?

```
$.getJSON(dataSource, function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + key + '</li>');
    });

    $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

below are the JSON column names and value returned from teh REST service

```
  * aprop : 1
* bprop : 7935408
* cprop : 2010-09-21 00:00:00.0
* dprop : Y
* eprop : 2
* fprop : 2010-09-21 16:10:22.0
* gprop : 3
* hprop : 10407198
* iprop : 4
```

DataTable

```
oTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({
    bJQueryUI: true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    //Pagination": "full_numbers",
    "sPaginationType": "two_button",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": 'RequestTrades.htm',
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": "110%",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "bSearchable": false,
        "bVisible": false,
        "aTargets": [1]
    }],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sName": "aprop" }, 
        { "sName": "bprop" }, 
        { "sName": "cprop" }, 
        { "sName": "dprop" }, 
        { "sName": "eprop" }, 
        { "sName": "fprop" }, 
        { "sName": "gprop" }, 
        { "sName": "hprop" }, 
        { "sName": "iprop" }
    ]
});
```

This is my table

```
<TABLE id=myTable cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">
    <THEAD>
            <TR>
                    <TH width="100" >Col1</TH>
                    <TH width="100"  >Col2</TH>
                    <TH width="200" >Col3</TH>
                    <TH width="221" >Col4</TH>
                    <TH width="221" >Col5</TH>
                    <TH width="400" >Col6</TH>
                    <TH width="1200" >Co7</TH>
                    <TH width="221" >Col8</TH>
                    <TH width="221" >Col9</TH>
            </TR>
    </THEAD>
    <TBODY>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Can you post all of the code ? including the datatables init

Comment: @ManseUK i have added all the codes...